# ionic build to /dist folder instead of /www

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

When I run `ionic build`, it always builds a new `/dist` folder with all the contents you would normally find in the `/www` folder. I'm trying to update my `/www` folder but it never does, only updates the `/dist` folder.  Why is this occurring and why is my `/www` folder refusing to update with the new changes in the `/src` code?

I built my app with the `--prod` flag a few times, could that be why?

Comment: in angular-cli you can change the directory change the file "angular.json", is there some like this file in ionic?

Comment: there was outputPath value in angular.json which was saving the build `dist`.  changed it to `www` and it worked THANK YOU!

Comment: Thank you @Eliseo That's useful but is a way to specifically set the build on where to go for a purpose. like
   `ionic build --output-path=dist/dev` or `ionic build --dist=dist/dev`

Answer (score 2):

To change for all builds..

- Change the following to `angular-cli.json` (ng1) or `angular.json` (ng2+):

  ```
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/dev",
          }
        }
      }
  ```

To have multiple locations:

- Build with:

  `ng build --output-path=dist/dev`
- Or with multiple configurations:

  `ng build --output-path=wwwtest --configuration test`

Answer (score -1):

```
**run ng build first**

    www folder will be created not dist folder
on your netlify deployment setting set the following configuration 

Base directory  /**leave it blank its optional**/ 

Build command  ng build

Publish directory  www/  **replace with **www/** rather than **dist/**
```

Comment: This is hard to understand. Can you edit the formatting to make the answer more clear?